# How to end the action of the function?

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, vba

I want that, pressing the "buton", then finish what is doing at the moment. 
First I press a button for do some calculations, it finishes between 3 or 4 minuts, and I want that presing a button could end, still the programe hasn't finished his work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wrote a function which is repeating himself and you want that function to stop what it is doing...

You could write code for your "buton" that it will set a boolean to true.

> Private _MustTheFunctionStop as boolean = false

Set this boolean as a global field in your class so your function can acces the boolean too.

When you click your button set the boolean to TRUE.

Then in your function you need to loop your code

a do while should do the trick

> ```
> > public function SomeCalculations
> > 
> > do while MustTheFunctionStop = false
> > 
> > /your code.../
> ```
>
> > end function

Comment: That wont work.   The UI will not be responsive while SomeCalculations is running

Answer (score 0):

Use Threads (pure Threads, BackgroundWorker or anything else).
The start button starts the thread only and gives the GUI control back,
to get indermediate results you´ll need some synchronization
and to end the thread before it it finished too.

Answer (score 0):

Use BackgroundWorker and SupportsCancellation

In do work check for CancellationPending
If do work does not have a loop then there is not a good way to cancel

[BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)